# Promql: Is it possible to get total count in Query_Range

Tags: prometheus, promql

For example, I have a prometheus query which return "1" on HTTP status 200 and "0" on HTTP status other than 200.
Now, I am using the query_range api where I pass the time range (start and end) and the step.

```
API-Endpoint: http://my-prometheus.com/api/v1/query_range
Query: http_response_ok{appname="XXX"}
Start: 2020-06-17T00:00:00
end:2020-06-17T23:59:59
step: 300000ms     (=5min)
```

The above query return me the data of every 5mins for the entire day in a form of "0" and "1". Total 289 point approx.

Is it possible to get the total count of all "1" and "0" for that specific time period ?
I have tried **count_over_time** which gives the total count. How to add a filter so that it returns the count when value == 0 or 1

```
count_over_time(http_response_ok{appname="XXX"}[24h])
```

FYI, Actual query is not http_request and I can' use http_request_total

Answer (score 2, accepted):

After doing some research I was able to find the answer. Basically inside the {} we are doing checks b/w label. Outside the {} we can put the condition for values.

So, to find the total counts where value is ==1 in past 24hrs, the query should be like this:

```
count_over_time(http_response_ok{appname="XXX"==1}[24h:])
```

And to find the total counts where value is ==0 in past 24hrs, the query should be like this:

```
count_over_time(http_response_ok{appname="XXX"==0}[24h:])
```

Answer (score 0):

Note that the [/api/v1/query_range](https://prometheus.io/docs/prometheus/latest/querying/api/#range-queries) returns **calculated** results instead of raw samples stored in the database. It returns exactly `1 + (end - start) / step` samples on the `[start ... end]` time range with `step` interval between them, where `start`, `end` and `step` are the corresponding query args passed to `/api/v1/query_range`. See [these docs](https://prometheus.io/docs/prometheus/latest/querying/basics/#staleness) for details on how Prometheus calculates the returned results. If you need to obtain raw samples, then a range query must be sent to [/api/v1/query](https://prometheus.io/docs/prometheus/latest/querying/api/#instant-queries).  For example, `/api/v1/query?query=http_response_ok[24h]&time=t` would return raw samples on the time range `(t-24h ... t]`. See [this article](https://valyala.medium.com/analyzing-prometheus-data-with-external-tools-5f3e5e147639) for details.

If the `http_response_ok` time series can have only 0 or 1 values, then the following queries can be used for returning the exact number of raw samples with 0 and 1 values:

- The number of raw samples with `1` value over the last 24 hours:

```
avg_over_time(http_response_ok[24h]) * count_over_time(http_response_ok[24h])
```

- The number of raw samples with `0` value over the last 24 hours:

```
(1 - avg_over_time(http_response_ok[24h])) * count_over_time(http_response_ok[24h])
```

How do these queries work? They use [avg_over_time()](https://docs.victoriametrics.com/MetricsQL.html#avg_over_time) function for calculating the average value for raw samples over the last 24 hours. Internally this value is calculated as `sum(raw_samples) / count(raw_samples)`. Then the result is multiplied by [count_over_time()](https://docs.victoriametrics.com/MetricsQL.html#count_over_time), which returns the number of raw samples over the last 24 hours, e.g. it equals to `count(raw_samples)`.

So the first query is equivalent to `sum(raw_samples) / count(raw_samples) * count(raw_samples) = sum(raw_samples)`. Since `raw_samples` may have only 0 and 1 values, then `sum(raw_samples) = count(raw_samples_equal_to_1)`.

The second query equals to `(1 - sum(raw_samples)/count(raw_samples)) * count(raw_samples) = count(raw_samples) - sum(raw_samples) = count(raw_samples) - count(raw_samples_equal_to_1) = count(raw_samples_equal_to_0)`.

If the `http_response_ok` time series can contain other values than 0 and 1, then queries listed above won't work. In this case [count_gt_over_time](https://docs.victoriametrics.com/MetricsQL.html#count_gt_over_time), [count_le_over_time](https://docs.victoriametrics.com/MetricsQL.html#count_le_over_time), [count_eq_over_time](https://docs.victoriametrics.com/MetricsQL.html#count_eq_over_time) and [count_ne_over_time](https://docs.victoriametrics.com/MetricsQL.html#count_ne_over_time) functions from MetricsQL may help.